# pandas extracting substring from column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['ABCXDEF', 'ABCYDEF']})
```

How can I extract the string that is surrounded by `ABC` & the first occurrence of `DEF`? Desired output:

```
    col
0   X
1   Y
```

Note that I don't want a solution based on exact positions, like:

```
df.col.str[3:4]
```

Comment: ```df.col.str.extract(r"((?<=ABC).+(?=DEF))")```

Comment: Sorry my bad. Incomplete question: but it needs to be the first occurence of `DEF`. For example, if the string is `ABCXDEFDEFDEF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(update: look for the first occurrence of 'DEF') 
Use this regex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['ABCXDEF', 'ABCYDEFDEFDEF']})
print(df.col.str.extract(r"ABC(.*?)DEF"))
```

The result is:

```
   0
0  X
1  Y
```